# UINavigationController and side menu

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift4

I'm starting with iOS, swift4.. development anyway, have following problem. I need to show  side menu, after cell item in UICollectionView component is tapped. The actual problem is that side menu view controller need to have transparent background. Side menu need to be connected to same ui bar back button, which means when user press on back button side menu should be popped. I was trying with many different aproaches but none of then helped me.

For example I tried with adding side menu as child view controller of main screen, but back press was not working well:

```
self.navigationController?.addChildViewController(controller)
controller.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(controller.view)
controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

I was also tried with pushViewController, but then side menu view controller is not transparent, of course in that case back navigation was working. Without using navigation controller is not option, except if I handle back navigation totally by my own logic.. but this is pretty ugly then I guess. Images of what I'm a trying to do:

[image: Wire frames example:]

Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so which method should I override, to back press callback, popViewcontroller can't be overriden, because Side view controller is not extending from Navigation view controller.. also not main view controller...

Answer (score 0):

Use this library, it provides great customizable features for side menu.Plus, it will be easy for you to manage as you wont have to need to create the entire menu by yourself.

https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController